# How to use Domain and Context in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo

How to use Domain and Context in odoo?
I have a situation for example, 
In OpenEduCat List of Subjects and List of Students.
Students are registered against subjects.
I want to show all students related to specific subject(English) in tree view.
Model A (students.course), Model B(results)
When i click on Subject then open a list view of students belongs to that Subject.

Answer (score 0):

```
domain="[('student', '=',subject)]"
```